# Shouldn't iterator_traits<vector<bool>::iterator>::iterator_category be input_iterator_tag?

Tags: c++, iterator, type-traits, stl-algorithm

I recently learned that *ForwardIterator*s require `operator *` to return by reference, which means that iterators that
return proxies, such as `std::vector<bool>`, cannot be *ForwardIterator*s
([[forward.iterators]](http://eel.is/c++draft/forward.iterators)).

However, I tested `std::iterator_traits<std::vector<bool>::iterator>::iterator_category` in different compilers
([G++](https://godbolt.org/z/pA9EeV), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/3WFTOZ), [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/PxC-uv)) and it
was always `std::random_access_iterator_tag`. Is that consistent with the above requirement?

Comment: The firs rule of SO C++ is: we don't talk about `std::vector<bool>`. Guess what the second rule is :D

Comment: @YSC I didn't know that ^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. That's part of the big issue with `vector<bool>`.

The standard contradicts itself. It says that `vector`'s iterators are random access, but defines `vector<bool>` in such a way that its iterators don't fulfill the requirements of `RandomAccessIterator`.

This ancient paper by Herb Sutter explains this and other downsides: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/N1185.pdf

Comment: Wow. It's therefore a long standing issue. As long as the standard itself.